# Excel Macro to Remove Duplicate

Tags: vba, excel

I need help creating an Excel Macro.

I have 2 columns: **A** holds computer name, **B** holds application name and version.

Column A will have duplicates computer names but I only need to count it listed by the newer application version. For example computer 3 shows ups 2 times for Acrobat 3 and Acrobat 5.
I just need to delete the Acrobat 3 line or not count it.

The computer name when it's duplicate always together. So computer 3 with Acrobat 5 would be above the row that had computer 3 with Acrobat 3.

This all affects the pivot table I have for each application.

Rowlabel is the application name. Value is a count on machine name. This groups all the machines that have the same application into a number so I can see how machines have a certain version installed.

GreenWeenie's solution worked to sort out all the duplicates with the same version, but I need to cover the situation here:

```
LT133059    VISIO Std 2010
LT133059    VISIO Std 2002

LT133274    VISIO Std 2002
LT133274    VISIO Std 2010
```

I need to count the higher version for the same machine name.

Here is some sample data.

```
Computer        Application
LT133255    VISIO Std 2002
LT133265    VISIO Std 2010
LT133274    VISIO Std 2002
LT133274    VISIO Std 2010
LT133276    VISIO Std 2002
LT133276    VISIO Std 2002
LT133059    VISIO Std 2010
LT133059    VISIO Std 2002
```

Comment: Does column B always have the application followed by a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming row 1 has column titles, and the data starts on row 2.

Add a helper column "C" with the following formula

```
=A2&TRIM(LEFT(B2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","|", LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""))))))
```

This strips off everything after the last space in the Application field, which should remove the version number, and appends it to the computer name.

Add a helper column "D" with the following Formula

```
=IF(MATCH(C2,C:C,0)=ROW(C2),1,0)
```

This returns a value of 1 when it is the first instance of a Computer/Software title

Have your pivot table sum column D.

Comment: This works, but I've run into a problem. I have some cases where the machine is the same, but it counts 1 for the older application. I would need the 1 to be the higher version same computer.

Comment: Can you paste an example of the software titles that aren't "matching"?  Could it be that one of them has a trailing space?  Or the computer name has a trailing space?

Comment: Thanks for the help so far GreenWeenie. I modified my question to show some sample data and the ones that aren't matching.

Comment: Can you sort your data with the software title descending?  Forget that... it will run into a problem with v9 & v10